# Remove some attributes from 3rd party CSS class

Tags: html, css

I have 3d party CSS, with

```
.STL {
  left: 50%;
}
```

I want to use right instead of left, so in my own style which loaded after 3rd-party I add:

```
.STL {
  right: 20px;
}
```

But seems like left have more priority (when I disable it in dev-tools in 3rd party it works).

I tried:

```
.STL {
  left: none !important;
  right: 20px;
}
```

But dev-tools say that value invalid. What I missed?

Comment: `left: none` is probably invalid. Valid values are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)

Comment: You must set `left:0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this, it will work surely.

```
.STL {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if this is written after the 3rd party CSS `!important` should not be required as it will already have higher priority.

Comment: Coz i dont know your code so i have written !important. !important is only to set high priority. You can simply write left:auto; , or if you want high priority then you should write left: auto !important;.

Answer (score 1):

none is invalid for 'left'. Try

```
.STL {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: 0 means that element left position is 0. I don't need left: 0 at all, I need only 20 from right.

Comment: You want Auto U3233135 has got it.